# Laravel HTML and SQL sanitisation

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, sanitization

What are the appropriate ways to do  HTML sanitisation and SQL sanitisation in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL sanitisation is handled automatically. From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries):

> Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

[Blade templates](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates) automatically escape variables when using curly brackets, e.g. `{{ $var }}`. If you do not want to escape the HTML, you need to use `{!! $var !!}` instead.

Comment: Laravel 4 is `{{{ $var }}}` to escape